# HTML5 Presentation onslide load event

Tags: jquery, html

I am creating a HTML5 presentation. I would want to catch a new slide load event? not sure how that can be done.

Preferably I would like add a jquery effect on a slide after it has loaded.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement is very vague.

Are your slides  elements with text? are they images? Can you share some code?

You can also find hundreds of jquery slide / gallery plugins which will give you dozen effect options out of the box.

[Check this list of jquery plugins](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/57-free-image-gallery-slideshow-and-lightbox-solutions/)

Comment: Its an HTML5 Presentation like that on http://slides.html5rocks.com/ 

Each Slide has html elements in it.

The idea is to catch the next slide event and perform some jquery/javascript on it

Answer (score 0):

You can download the minimal version of slides.html5rocks.com which is ready for you to adapt to your use.

> [Download Sample](http://studio.html5rocks.com/#Deck)